# Silverlight printing on a Mac (non-letter format)

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have having a bit of a problem that may be an issue with my code or it might be an issue with the client not realizing something he needs to do. I am developing a Silverlight5 app that prints and is used by both Windows machines and Mac Machines. The problem is that our printouts will not be on the standard letter (8.5" x 11") paper size. On Windows I get a print dialog that let's me set up the size and orientation (Landscape/Portrait) of the document I have loaded. The client gets a dialog, but that dialog does not let him specify landscape orientation (it's a different dialog than his normal Safari dialog).

So the question is there something I need to do in my code to enable Landscape printing on a Mac OR is my client missing something in the Mac print dialog for Silverlight?

Comment: I figured it out... but I needed to figure out how to get Landscape printing on a Mac. I thought it was something being missed in the environment, but nope.. it had to be accounted for with code.

Comment: What I meant is that you're supposed to ask questions on SO, and your post is only describing a problem. Glad you found out, and thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: I guess I can see that it wasn't clearly spelled out.. it is now..

Comment: BTW, I was hoping I wouldn't have to figure it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the specific answer that I have turned up.

Direct Landscape printing is not possible. You have to turn your printed visual manually (well, with code).

I wrote a blog post on this here -- http://www.jaykimble.net/forced-landscape-printing-in-silverlight-on-a-mac.aspx